# Access UNION query yields unreadable results when Null row precedes other data

Tags: ms-access, null, ms-access-2013, union-all

I have an Access 2013 database with a table named [carInsurance] as follows:

[image]

Now I want to display all the data in this table along with an "empty" row full of NULL values. So I use a UNION query to accomplish that as follows:

```
select NULL as insId, NULL as carId, NULL as insFromDate from carInsurance 
UNION 
select insId, carId, insFromDate from carInsurance
```

However, the results show up like this

[image]

and when I use UNION ALL as follows:

```
select NULL as insId, NULL as carId, NULL as insFromDate from carInsurance 
UNION ALL 
select insId, carId, insFromDate from carInsurance
```

I get all results correct except that I get an empty line for every result. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to go on a hunch.  I think it is because of different data types being chosen when you give it just NULL.  Beats me why it would be different for `UNION` vs `UNION ALL`.

Try this:

```
Select 
    cast (NULL as int) as insId, 
    cast (NULL as int) as carId, 
    cast (NULL as Date) as insFromDate 
from carInsurance 
UNION  
Select insId, carId, insFromDate from carInsurance
```

Extending the same line of thought, I would suggest is reversing the order of your SELECTs:

```
Select insId, carId, insFromDate from carInsurance 
UNION  
Select NULL as insId, NULL as carId, NULL as insFromDate from carInsurance
```

Comment: I get the following message: Syntax Error(missing operator) in query expression 'cast (NULL as int)

Comment: All right, your second solution works perfectly without any problem. Thank you Mr. Raj

Comment: Mr. Raj, any idea why when I try to save data using adapter.update(ds,"table") it show the following error: Dynamic SQL generation is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not return any base table information.

Comment: Are you querying a table or a view?  If table, does your table have a Primary Key?